# Why am I getting boot errors after a fresh Windows install?

Tags: windows-7, boot, checksum

I have a really strange problem. I have a new laptop (no guaranty) and everytime after a clean installation everything is perfectly fine. But when the laptop is powered off for a couple of hours I get this error:

> The file may be corrupt. The file header checksum does not match the computed checksum

Also some other errors are thrown like:

```
\boot\bcd
0xc0000034
```

It seems that something is corrupted at the moment when the power is off. But how is this possible?

So far I've tried:

- replacing ram (no effect)
- other harddrive (no effect)
- I tried 3 different OS (XP, Vista and windows 7)

It's a Toshiba Satellite A300d notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This error occurs when either of the
> following conditions is true:
>
> The
> Windows Boot Manager (Bootmgr) entry
> is not present in the Boot
> Configuration Data (BCD) store.
>
> The
> Boot\BCD file on the active partition
> is damaged or missing.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927391

Comment: True, but why is this happening? It's a clean installation, new ram and harddisk.

Comment: Heres a reasonably thorough explanation: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/1054294.html To do with BIOS boot order during installation of V/7.. XP should have worked though. Odd indeed.